# Click a button on a page to increment a counter in another page using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

so as the title says, I've a button on my main page which should send the amount of times clicked to another page.

I know how to do this via JS, but not in PHP. PHP is also not live, so I'd need to refresh the webpage in order to see the effect, I've been reading about it and I might try and mess around with AJAX to refresh a certain element of my webpage.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: If it goes to another page, don't you have to load that other page to see the effect? Or do you have both pages open in different browser windows?

Comment: Yes, I do have both pages open with different browser windows. Forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should save it somewhere because PHP is handled server side. So either a cookie/session or a database.

Comment: I see, so save it the increment on the DB everytime the button is clicked and then display the query in the other page, right?